# Why can't I require express in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to get the simplest node.js script to work. Here is the javascript file:

**server.js**

```
require("express");
```

I launch the script using the regulare node command:

```
$ node server.js
```

But I get an error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead.
    at Function.<anonymous> (module.js:378:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shawn/.node_libraries/express@2.5.9/index.js:4:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shawn/Documents/Projets/passingData/server.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
```

What's going on?

**UPDATE**

Interestingly enough, using `npm install express` outputs a similar result:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead.
    at Function.<anonymous> (module.js:378:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shawn/.node_libraries/mkdirp@0.3.0/index.js:4:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/dir-reader.js:11:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
```

Comment: Have you done `npm install express` yet?

Comment: `npm install express` also causes an error, see my edit.

Comment: Looks like you have old npm. Try to update node.js and npm to current stable versions.

Comment: Either `npm` or `node` or both are outdated.

Comment: I installed the latest version of Node (npm comes with it), and now I get a different error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163447/error-require-paths-is-removed-use-node-modules-folders-or-the-node-path-envi

Answer (score 1):

you need to install it globally like this (if you don't build it as package)

```
npm install express -g
```

or if you have it in `package.json` you have to do local install `npm install -l` and it will work fine.

Comment: You could omit the "-l". Just create a `package.json` and do `npm install`.