# Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead

Tags: node.js, express

I just freshly installed Node.js and now I'm trying to run a simple script, but I get the following error message:

```
Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead.
    at Function.<anonymous> (module.js:383:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shawn/.node_libraries/express@2.5.9/index.js:4:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shawn/Documents/Projets/jsonpExchange/server.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
```

What does it mean, and how can I solve it?

UPDATE:

```
$ node -v

v0.6.19

$ npm install express

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
express@2.5.10 ./node_modules/express
├── qs@0.4.2
├── mime@1.2.4
├── mkdirp@0.3.0
└── connect@1.9.0 (formidable@1.0.11)
```

Answer (score 4):

This error happens when some installed packages are built for an older version of nodejs.

Which version of node are you using?

```
$ node -v
```

Are you using npm (http://npmjs.org) to install packages? The output of install express should be like this:

```
$ npm install express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/-/connect-1.9.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/-/connect-1.9.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
express@2.5.10 ./node_modules/express
├── qs@0.4.2
├── mkdirp@0.3.0
├── mime@1.2.4
└── connect@1.9.0 (formidable@1.0.11)
```

Comment: You may also try to remove the /home/shawn/.node_libraries/ directory

Comment: Removing /home/shawn/.node_libraries/ solved the problem. Add it to your answer and I shall accept it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have an old local (user-specific) installation of `coffee-script`.

Here's what I did :

1. deleted my `~/.node_modules` folder
2. deleted relevant binaries in `~/bin` folder
3. reinstall `coffee-script` : `sudo npm install --global coffee-script`

Now it works :)